# PS4 account shared among other users

Tags: ps4, psn

My son shared his account to several players, those players made charges in to his account and credit card, so to whom these purchases are credited, to my son account or to the other players account?

Comment: Account sharing should never be done especially if there is credit card or other payment information stored. Hopefully these other players are friends or relatives and not random other online users.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on who was logged in at the time of purchase.  If your son's account was logged in, the purchases are credited to his account, and use the wallet and credit card info on his account.

If his friends are signed in as themselves, then purchases are credited to their own account.